# How to keep the ML model of Spacy running in a Django app

Tags: django, performance, nlp, spacy

I am working on an NLP project in SpaCy. I want to deploy my project on the internet using Django, but I have a performance issue. The app checks a sentence for its grammatical correctness and it is fast once the ML model is loaded with the command spacy.load('en'). The problem is that loading the ML model takes around 30 seconds. How can I keep the ML model running so that it doesn't have to reload/restart every time a new request comes in on the server?

Answer (score 3):

A good idea would be to load your models at your settings.py file.

Have a look at [this](http://www.nlpbuddy.io/) project, it is built on spaCy with Django. 
The project is open source and the loading utility you are searching for is available [here](https://github.com/eellak/nlpbuddy/blob/7dfb5133868da6cc572752b31bdf444ed783c4e1/demo/settings.py#L158).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The first link does not work. Do you know how I can take a look at the project? I am starting to use `SpaCy` in a project that has `Angular` as frontend and `Django` as backend and `MongoDB` as database. I need to run sentiment analysis on user feedback, which is just text that the user enters in different fields of a web form (Angular). I would appreciate any hints or tips you might have, or perhaps a similar project that I could take a look at. Thanks